# What to do if the Editor is not responding to my repeated e-mails?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, editors, withdraw

This is in reference to my previous question:
[How to mail the editor asking to withdraw my submission?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/116927/96599)

I wrote to the editor regarding my problem for 2 consecutive days.
I sent 4 mails to him regarding the withdrawal of my manuscript.

But I have not received a single reply from him.

How long should I wait? I know he is busy too but I need to do it fast as my Masters (Research) course will end in 2 months and I need to have it at least communicated if not published within this duration.

Otherwise I won't get my degree.
But why is the Editor not replying to my e-mails?

I need to resubmit it fast to either this journal or another journal.

Please help me, I don't understand what should I do.

Comment: Keep in mind that editors of academic journals are almost always volunteers.  They have their own jobs, usually as professors, and are busy with teaching, research and administration, which they actually get paid for.  They will get to their journal work when they can, but it can't be their top priority.

Comment: Seriously? _Four_ e-mails in _two_ days? I wouldn't be surprised if the editor was annoyed by your impudence and will take as much time as they can before answering you. The fact you're short on time doesn't mean everything revolves around you. Might be harsh words, but you are the only one to blame for the flaw you found after the paper went under review. Ultimately, **talk with your advisor**. I don't believe you _won't get your degree_ – you will, but maybe with a delay. You need to come to terms with it; take a deep breath and stop panicking.

Comment: To expand upon @corey979 's comment, in North America, you posted this question on a Sunday, at the end of the weekend. Two days ago would have been sometime of Friday. The editor has had less than 1 full business day to respond.

Comment: Cannot you do it online through the submission portal?

Comment: Your degree depends on you publishing a paper within the duration of your masters? I highly doubt it, since this requirement is complete madness. Submitting a manscript takes time, and getting it published after that *also* takes time, often more than a year, and sometimes several.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Giving someone 2 days to respond to an email, especially about a submission, is **no where near long enough**. I wouldn't expect a response that fast for virtually anything. 4 emails is definitely excessive.

For a journal, I would expect 2 weeks to be a reasonable amount of time on this. Generally, anything of this nature is not urgent. You can certainly go ahead and begin preparing to submit the paper elsewhere (e.g., find a journal, correct your paper's mistake, and reformat the paper), but don't submit it yet.

Comment: +1, four emails in two days is beyond excessive.  Editors are likely volunteers.

Comment: +1, days when both of the days are weekends is even less unreasonable!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to wait for confirmation of the withdrawal note if you are going to send it to a different journal, now.  (Your withdrawal note, whenever viewed is enough to stop the publication process.)  If you want to resubmit to same journal, you will need to wait a while.